# Is there an easier way to compute derivatives of vector-valued functions with respect to parameter matrices in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

Say I have a simple Pytorch network parameterized by a matrix of size N x M, with output of size N x 1. I want to compute the derivative of the output of this network with respect to its parameters. The result I want has dimensions N x N x M (i.e., I need N derivatives for each parameter; one for each output), but after calling `output.backward(torch.ones_like(output))`, the gradients stored in the .grad attribute only have dimension N x M.

Currently my work-around is to loop over the elements of `output`, call `.backward()` on each of them individually, and stack the resulting gradients. But this is cumbersome as I also have to set the parameter `.grad` attributes back to zero after each `.backward()` call.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Edit: here's some code to illustrate what I mean.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc2(self.relu(self.fc1(x)))

model = Network(4, 5, 2)
inputs = torch.randn(1, 4)
output = model(inputs)
output.backward(torch.ones_like(output))
gradients = [param.grad for param in model.parameters()]
```

Result: `gradients` is a list of [a `5x4` tensor, a `5x1` tensor, a `2x5` tensor, and a `2x1` tensor].

Expected/desired result: a list of [a `2x5x4` tensor, a `2x5x1` tensor, a `2x2x5` tensor, and a `2x2x1` tensor].

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

How to compute the gradients on a multi value function through Pytorch is an interesting question by itself.

But normally we need the gradient of a loss function

```
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(...) # or another loss

output = model(inputs)
loss = loss_fn(outputs, data_labels)
loss.backward()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question, as my use case is not the typical derivative of a scalar loss. Thanks for taking the time to reply anyway!